# How to use system environment variables on cassandra.yaml

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, environment-variables, yaml

I'm fairly new using Cassandra and I had the following problem:

On the cassandra.yaml file, there's the data_file_directories, commitlog_directory and the saved_caches_directory parameters. I want to use my $HOME environment variable on it so my project will not be dependent on this.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

I'm using ubuntu, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Java is reading the configuration file, not a shell. Passing in non-multi-platform environment variables is tricky, so full paths are used.

I'm not clear what "so my project will not be dependent on this" actually refers to - multiple Cassandra instances on the same machine? See CCM: https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm

Since you mention you are using Ubuntu, I assume that you installed the deb package. The deb packages are set up to be run by the 'cassandra' user with /var/lib/cassandra and /var/log/cassandra as the default data and log locations, which are owned by the correct user. This "system" installation via deb packages is best used as-is, sticking to full paths. You could certainly use something like `sed` on the configuration file to change what you need, using $HOME from your shell to set the desired full paths, but then you'll also need to change the user in the init script, and work out other bugs you find along the way.

The simplest thing you could do? Run Cassandra 2.1 via tarball right in your $HOME. Version 2.1 was updated to default to writing the data and logs right in $CASSANDRA_HOME (the extracted tarball directory), instead of /var/{lib,log}/cassandra.

- Download apache-cassandra-2.1.*-bin.tar.gz (the current version) from http://cassandra.apache.org/download/
- `tar xzf apache-cassandra-2.1.*-bin.tar.gz`
- `cd apache-cassandra-2.1.*/`
- `./bin/cassandra`
- do what you need with your database
- `pkill -f CassandraDaemon` to stop Cassandra

Comment: Actually, my project is using Cassandra embedded. The path in cassandra.yaml can be different for Windows, Linux a OSX, for example.

My project can't depend on the OS, so use different paths is kinda tricky for me.